# ¿Por qué no se pueden dar dos recompensas de similar cantidad en la misma pregunta?

Tags: discusión, recompensas

El otro día puse una recompensa en [esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/20703/almacenamiento-en-base-de-datos-en-android-e-ios-con-cordova) y obtuve buenas respuestas. De hecho, al final estaba indeciso entre dos de las respuestas (la de [@fredyfx](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/21003/250) y [@devconcept](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/21353/250)) para darle la recompensa a una de las dos.

Finalmente, me decidí por una de ellas, y pensé en darle a la otra una recompensa similar por ser una respuesta ejemplar y valer una recompensa adicional... Y entonces me encontré con que no puedo hacerlo, sólo puedo dar una recompensa mayor que la original.

En el [centro de ayuda](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/bounty) encontré algo que explica la situación:

> - Adicionalmente, si ofreces múltiples recompensas en la misma pregunta, la reputación mínima a ofrecer se dobla para cada recompensa subsiguiente (50 puntos para la primera recompensa, 100 para la segunda, 200 para la tercera, y así sucesivamente).

Ahora mi pregunta es ¿por qué esa condición? No es que me queje, es sólo por curiosidad. No termino de comprender cuál es beneficio/ventaja de tener un sistema como ese. Además, ¿hay alguna manera de que pueda dar una recompensa de igual o menor cantidad a otro usuario en la misma pregunta?

Comment: Fijate mi [respuesta](http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/a/794/25), pero quiza esto es un feature-request, en el caso puntual de dar un "premio" a alguien mas, aparte del "ganador" de la recompensa.. es un caso fronterizo. No parece tener mucho sentido tener que dar el doble a la respuesta que _no elegiste_ como ganadora. Pero no funcionaria bajo el regimen de duración de una semana, por las razones explicadas abajo, en ese caso se tendería que aplicar directamente.

Answer (score 1):

Según se explica en este post de [Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/105275/abusing-bounties-for-unlimited-profit/105639#105639), la regla se agrego para evitar que una recompensa termine generando mas reputación de la que se ofreció en primer lugar y esto genere una oportunidad para especular.

Y tiene sentido, tu pregunta cosecho 10 votos y una medalla de bronce. Si hubieras ofrecido +50, hubieras quedado igualado, pero pudiste recibir mas votos y obtener cierta "ganancia" por decirlo de alguna forma.

Este caso, como ofreciste +250 no hay "negocio", pero la regla esta para evitar esta trampa.