# ¿Es posible que un moderador pueda cambiar una recompensa ya otorgada?

Tags: soporte, recompensas

Por error he dado una recompensa a otro usuario y no al que quería, como ya he visto yo no puedo revertir la situación, algún moderador puede hacer tal cosa? O de alguna manera, no sé.

Ha sido en esta pregunta:

[Barra de Búsqueda no busca en android.widget.ListView (Obtengo Títulos de Array)](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/46638/barra-de-b%C3%BAsqueda-no-busca-en-android-widget-listview-obtengo-t%C3%ADtulos-de-array)

Los +50 era para @StefanNolde y no para el otro usuario.

Comment: Por supuesto es el lugar indicado, debiste estar pendiente de la asignación del bounty o al menos asignarle un +1.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

De acuerdo con la FAQ del sitio Meta no es posible. Dice literalmente aquí: [How does the bounty system work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work)

> ## After awarding the bounty, can I remove it or move it to another answer at a later time?
>
> No, awarding is permanent. (But you're warned about that when actually awarding the bounty.)

Traducción libre:

> ## Después de otorgar la recompensa, ¿Puedo quitarla o moverla hacia otra respuesta en el futuro?
>
> No, el otorgamiento **es permanente**. (Pero fuiste advertido sobre ello cuando otorgabas la recompensa)

Parece bastante claro, una vez otorgada la recompensa no hay vuelta atrás.

Ten en cuenta que puedes otorgar una nueva recompensa, pero deberá ser del doble que la vez anterior :/ Ver: [¿Por qué no se pueden dar dos recompensas de similar cantidad en la misma pregunta?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/793/por-qu%C3%A9-no-se-pueden-dar-dos-recompensas-de-similar-cantidad-en-la-misma-pregun/794#794)